# How to open jquery dialog on menu click

Tags: 7, ajax, javascript

I would like to open a jquery dialog that asks a question before taking the user to the desired page (ie do some page set-up before they get there). The catch here is that I would like to open the dialog when the user clicks the menu item. I am not sure how to go about this. Could someone point me to some examples where this is done or what I need to do? I am using Drupal 7.

Thanks.

Comment: there is a module which might be helpful - http://drupal.org/project/modal_forms

Comment: Thanks for the link to that project it looks like I could use on a future project, but for the a current project that I am working on now I would like to do it programmatically.

Comment: I've got something like that. I did it with the help of MYTHEME_menu_link__menu_my_menu($variables) there I customized the link behavior to open the dialog

Comment: try [ctools](http://drupal.org/project/ctools) module

Comment: Hi, can you provide a sample code :) .

Answer (score 0):

You can use dialog ui or colorbox, just attach this scripts to the page and add custom click event for menu item to open popup. Or you can use ctools but it's more complex.